# Hibernate sequence increments parent id for each child insert

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Using hibernate, insert to child fails with "Referential integrity constraint violation" on child. Parent Id is incremented for each child.

```
// Parent: Composite primary key, one auto generated
@IdClass(PlanId.class)
public class PlanEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PlanIdGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PlanIdGenerator", sequenceName = "PLAN_ID_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Id
    private Long version;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "planEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true) //
    private Collection<PlanGoalBucketEntity> goalBuckets = new ArrayList<>();

public void addPlanGoalBucketEntity(PlanGoalBucketEntity goalBucket) {
    goalBuckets.add(goalBucket);
    goalBucket.setPlanEntity(this);
}

public void removePosition(PlanGoalBucketEntity goalBucket) {
    goalBuckets.remove(goalBucket);
    goalBucket.setPlanEntity(null);
}
.....    
}
```

//Child

```
public class PlanGoalBucketEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "plan_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "version", referencedColumnName = "version") })
    private PlanEntity planEntity;

    .....
}
```

Insert to planentity (parent) with one PlanGoalBucketEntity (child) is all good.

Inserting parent with multiple child, it fails with foreign key violation "Referential integrity constraint violation". Inserting first child is fine but second child fails because it increments parent id for second child.

Couldn't figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Turns out foreign key reference was wrong. (Check detailed answer). Leaving the question open as it might help others.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't pasted your PlanId class, but I assume it is something like this

```
public class PlanId implements Serializable {

    public Long id;
    public Long version;
}
```

I copied your code and the following test works, all I did was implement PlanId as above and added necessary setters in your entities. I am using an H2 DB

```
    @Test
    public void plan() {
        PlanEntity planEntity = new PlanEntity();
        planEntity.setVersion(1L);

        planEntity.addPlanGoalBucketEntity(new PlanGoalBucketEntity());
        planEntity.addPlanGoalBucketEntity(new PlanGoalBucketEntity());

        planEntityRepository.save(planEntity);

        // Check save of 2 plan goal buckets is successful

        List<PlanEntity> planEntities =
                entityManager.createQuery(
                        "select distinct p from PlanEntity p left join fetch p.goalBuckets", PlanEntity.class)
                        .getResultList();

        assertEquals(1, planEntities.size());
        assertEquals(2, planEntities.iterator().next().getGoalBuckets().size());
    }

// JpaRepository

@Repository
public interface PlanEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<PlanEntity, PlanId> {}
```

Comment: Im using JPA repository, not sure if it makes a difference

Comment: I changed to using a JpaRepository and it is still working, maybe you should include more of your code

Comment: My bad, my foreign key reference was wrong. Thanks for you help